# Javascript Function only working for 1st element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have made a editable div inside of foreignObject and made a function which can change the height & width of foreignObject according to the height & width of editable div inside it. But the problem is that the function is working only for the first element not for all the elements with the same class. Please take a look at my code.

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
  d3.select(window).on("input", function(e) {
    var wd = document.querySelector(".myDiv").scrollWidth;
    var hd = document.querySelector(".myDiv").scrollHeight;
    document.querySelector(".frobj").setAttribute("width", wd);
    document.querySelector(".frobj").setAttribute("height", hd);
  })
</script>

<svg class="graph" viewBox="0 0 500 500"
     style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

  <foreignObject class="frobj" x="100" y="0" width="35px" height="23px"
                 style='background:red'>
    <div class="myDiv" contenteditable="true"
         style="font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;">
      Text
    </div>
  </foreignObject>

  <foreignObject class="frobj" x="100" y="50" width="35px" height="23px"
                 style='background:red'>
    <div class="myDiv" contenteditable="true"
         style="font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;">
      Text
    </div>
  </foreignObject>

  <foreignObject class="frobj" x="100" y="100" width="35px" height="23px"
                 style='background:red'>
    <div class="myDiv" contenteditable="true"
         style="font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;">
      Text
    </div>
  </foreignObject>

</svg>
```

Comment: `.querySelector()` only returns the first matching element. You can use `.querySelectorAll()` to return a **list** of elements. You can then iterate through the list to operate on each element individually.

Comment: Can you please make a working code, because I have used .querySelectorAll and it is not working when we use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full working example.

You need to use `.querySelectorAll()` and then loop over each of those with `forEach()` and then do your adjustments inside of that callback function.

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
  d3.select(window).on("input", function(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".frobj").forEach(el => {
      var wd = el.querySelector(".myDiv").scrollWidth;
      var hd = el.querySelector(".myDiv").scrollHeight;
      el.setAttribute("width", wd);
      el.setAttribute("height", hd);
    });    
  })
</script>

<svg class="graph" viewBox="0 0 500 500"
     style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

  <foreignObject class="frobj" x="100" y="0" width="35px" height="23px"
                 style='background:red'>
    <div class="myDiv" contenteditable="true"
         style="font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;">
      Text
    </div>
  </foreignObject>

  <foreignObject class="frobj" x="100" y="50" width="35px" height="23px"
                 style='background:red'>
    <div class="myDiv" contenteditable="true"
         style="font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;">
      Text
    </div>
  </foreignObject>

  <foreignObject class="frobj" x="100" y="100" width="35px" height="23px"
                 style='background:red'>
    <div class="myDiv" contenteditable="true"
         style="font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;">
      Text
    </div>
  </foreignObject>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just selecting the first one. In order to select all you need to use **querySelectorAll()** instead

Comment: Can you please make a working code, because I have used .querySelectorAll and it is not working when we use it.

Comment: You need to iterate through each using a loop and then you set the attributes

Comment: Do you know how loops work? If not, I suggest you take at look at that first. querySelectorAll will return a NodeList. In order to access each individual element, you need to iterate using a loop (i.e.: foreach). Then you can set your values inside